# Maven `dependency:purge-local-repository` doesn't remove all dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I know that there are few questions already about `dependency:purge-local-repository` to clean up the local repository dependency cache.

Almost all posts say this command will remove all dependencies but it seems not...
Especially "test" scope dependencies remain and I can't clean up the local repo.

I debugged this plugin a bit and why this happens.
Then eventually I found that the `getFilteredResolvedArtifacts` method in the `PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo` calls `MavenSession.getProjectBuildingRequest()` method and this `ProjectBuildingRequest` has an exclude for `test` & `provided` scopes in the `buildingRequest.repositorySession.dependencySelector`

Source => https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/528a2f9b6683ada0b2cabad8593cd814fd08a1b2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo.java#L578-L580

Screenshot of debugging => [debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tfiO.png)

I would like to know if this plugin intentionally excludes test dependencies to purge (if so, the reason as well..)
I wanted to rise a github issue for that (https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin) but I couldn't find issue page there.

Thanks a lot for the support in advance!